# Selenium Web Driver Java Element class How?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to catch an element and sendKeys , becouse my code does not work

Screen 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w50S.jpg)

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched')]")).sendKeys("Test")

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: When you put that xpath in chrome dev tools(ctrl+f once dev tools is open for windows), does it match the right text box, and only one?

Comment: Yes , do you know how?

Comment: What do you mean by "my code does not work"? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen? If you get an error, what is it? My best guess right now is that selector is matching more than one element, so it's not putting the text in the box

Comment: element was not found. maybe some xpatch ? Do you know how?

Comment: My next guess is you're running into some problem waiting. You can try this xpath as an alternative, but I think you're running into a different problem. `//*[text()[contains(., 'Nazwa:')]]/input`

Comment: If you want to test to see if waiting is the problem, you can add a `Thread.sleep(5000);` right before you search for the element. If that works then you need to use an explicit wait for something on the page to make sure the page is ready for your next step.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebdriverWait` to identify the element and then use sendKeys.I have provided XPATH as well CssSelector.Hope this helps.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched']")));
element.sendKeys("Test");
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ng-valid-parse")));
element.sendKeys("Test");
```

If it does not work then check if there any frame avaialable.If does you have to switch to frame first.then you will be able to access the element.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame-name");
```